# How do I get Local folder size in Windows 8.1 (winRT)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have an Windows 8.1 Store App. I am trying to find the  Local Folder Size.?(e.g. 210 MB)

I have an application which would download some of content into my local folder. I want to check the size of my local folder (such as how many MB are currently there).

I have tried looking through MSDN and Google but haven't been able to find anything on it.

Note : I have a folder and subfolder so not only files which is in local folder..

Answer (score 8):

You are able to access the `LocalFolder` via the [`ApplicationData.LocalFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.ASPx) property.

This `LocalFolder` is a [`StorageFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx) object. `StorageFolder` has a method called [`GetBasicPropertiesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getbasicpropertiesasync).

`GetBasicPropertiesAsync` returns a [`BasicProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties) object. This `BasicProperties` object has a [`Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.size) property which tells you the size of the item in question (folder or file). I believe that `Size` is in bytes (a `ulong`).

The complete command can be done in a single line in an `async` method like this:

`(await ApplicationData.LocalFolder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).Size;`

You can also split up each step if you need any other information.

Edit: Apparently this does not work as well as hoped. The solution is to create a query and sum up all of the files. You can do this using Linq.

```
using System.Linq;

// Query all files in the folder. Make sure to add the CommonFileQuery
// So that it goes through all sub-folders as well
var folders = ApplicationData.LocalFolder.CreateFileQuery(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);

// Await the query, then for each file create a new Task which gets the size
var fileSizeTasks = (await folders.GetFilesAsync()).Select(async file => (await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).Size);

// Wait for all of these tasks to complete. WhenAll thankfully returns each result
// as a whole list
var sizes = await Task.WhenAll(fileSizeTasks);

// Sum all of them up. You have to convert it to a long because Sum does not accept ulong.
var folderSize = sizes.Sum(l => (long) l);
```

Comment: Updated it, hope that helps

Comment: this is not giving me size but it will show me only 0(zero)

Comment: Seems like that doesn't work and it makes some sense. Size isn't a quick thing to get on large folders so to be able to get basic properties quickly - it shouldn't be returned in the basic properties call. I tried some extended properties, but those don't seem to work either, so you're probable best off calculating it yourself by iterating on all files in the folder.

Comment: I think Filip might be right. This is easy to do with Linq though. Editing to include a solution.

Comment: This works brilliantly for me and IS quick <1s and is accurate: Only a few bytes out from File Explorer on 1.85M :)

Answer (score 2):

The C# solution is fine for small-medium size folders but if your app (for whatever reason) has large amount of files this method will take a lot of time and you may even run out of memory. I ran into this situation and opted to write a c++ winrt component that gets the size of a folder and I can attest that it runs much faster and with less memory. The code for the function is below, in the c# code you can call GetAppUsedSpace using the LocalState folder's Path property.

```
    #include "pch.h"
    #include "NativeFileHelper.h"

    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <stack>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>

    using namespace Platform;

    NativeFileHelper::NativeFileHelper()
    {
    }


    unsigned __int64 ListFiles(std::wstring path, std::wstring mask) {
        HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
        std::wstring spec;
        std::stack<std::wstring> directories;

        directories.push(path);

        unsigned __int64 result = 0;

        while (!directories.empty()) {
            path = directories.top();
            spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
            directories.pop();

            hFind = FindFirstFileEx(spec.c_str(), FindExInfoStandard, &ffd, FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS::FindExSearchNameMatch, NULL, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);
            if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  {
                return result;
            }

            do {
                if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 &&
                    wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                    if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                        directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                    }
                    else {
                        //This is file name
                        result += ffd.nFileSizeLow + (ffd.nFileSizeHigh * MAXDWORD);
                        //files.push_back(path + "\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                    }
                }
            } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
                FindClose(hFind);
                return result;
            }

            FindClose(hFind);
            hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }

        return result;
    }

    unsigned __int64 NativeFileHelper::GetAppUsedSpace(Platform::String^ pathOfFolder)
    {
        unsigned __int64 size = ListFiles(pathOfFolder->Data(), L"*");

        return size;
    }
```