# Get total size of LocalFolder Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, local-storage, winrt-xaml

In my app i am using LocalStorage. I have saved photos to localfolder. I want total used memory size of localfolder.

```
BasicProperties BP = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
var size = BP.Size;
Debug.WriteLine("size = {0}", size);
```

I am using this code but every time I am getting

> size = 0

I have looked at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249330/how-do-i-get-local-folder-size-in-windows-8-1-winrt) but i don't think its proper way to get total total size of localfolder i don't want to use for loop because there will be hundreds of file in my localfolder.

Answer (score 1):

You have to walk through folders to calculate the size of files inside

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<long> GetFolderSize(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder)
{
    long size = 0;
    // For files
    foreach (Windows.Storage.StorageFile thisFile in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
    {
        Windows.Storage.FileProperties.BasicProperties props = await thisFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        size += props.Size;
    }
    // For folders
    foreach (Windows.Storage.StorageFolder thisFolder in await folder.GetFoldersAsync())
    {
       size += await GetFolderSize(thisFolder);
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: so, there is no other way to calculate direct size of folder ??

Comment: No, the size of the folder is the sum of the files sizes inside it, simply