# UWP can‘t get a folder's size

Tags: uwp

I'm using the following code, but the result is always 0.

In fact, the local folder is 16MB.

```
StorageFolder cacheFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
BasicProperties bp = await cacheFolder.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
ulong cacheSizeByte = bp.Size; ​​​​
```

Is anyone knows why?

Comment: You mean the sum of the sizes of the files inside the folder is 16MB? The folder itself doesn't seem to have a size.

Comment: Yeah, the sum of files and sub-folders in the local folder. I once thought it may like a file's property, but not. Now the folder itself seems to be 0 always, I think I should use recursive to get the real size.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22273715/318501